# Passing Numbers in array format - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to convert string to an array format in my code below. I tried to use explode but it returns my results as

In my code i have

**File.php**

```
  $dial_deustche_no =  $payloadArray[1];

  dial_deustche_no =  49744990,49010101  //result

 $numbers = json_encode([0 => $dial_deustche_no]);
 
 $numbers =. ["49744990,49010101"]  //result
```

**When i use explode results looks like**

```
 explode(',', $numbers);

 //results

array (
  0 => '["49744990',
  1 => '49010101"]',
)
```

**This is how i want my results to look like**

```
$numbers = ['49744990','49010101']
```

PS: Beginner in laravel PHP

Comment: the `json_encode` return a string. and this string is `["0557447800,0501149794"]`. So of course when youn split it at the comma, it returns `["0557447800` and `0501149794"]`. Have you tried to `json_decode` it instead ?

Comment: when you added `dial_deustche_no =  49744990,49010101  //result` you meant `dial_deustche_no =  '49744990,49010101'` as a string right ?

Comment: That code should throw some syntax errors - what have you tried to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode it before doing the json_encode

```php
$numbers = explode(',', $payloadArray[1]);
```